# d3.js time axis on a radial/pie graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am building an arc graph where the start and end points of the arcs are times in one day. I have a d3 scale that converts date objects into radians, but I need a scale with four ticks applied around the outside of the graph. I did it with jQuery, and you can see how it's supposed to look below [image: here]

The problem I'm having is that the jQuery (and myself) is doing a poor job keeping those ticks at equal distances from the graph. Different screen sizes are making this a pain.

Does anyone have any idea how do create d3 time axis that is a circle? I've googled with no results.

[Here is a link to the live site](http://mateig.com/sleep_arcs)

Comment: Is your problem that the ticks you are looking to place may be farther or closer to the center of the circle depending on the number of arcs you are drawing on a particular graph?  That is, if you have data on 15 days on graph1 vs 5 days on graph 2, then the tick indicators on graph 1 will need to be farther away (ie. on a circle w/ a larger radius) than graph 2?  Also, the screen shot you have embedded does not appear to allow closer inspection, so its difficult to understand the effect you're after.  Your live site though is very interesting!